# SWIFT - UIBarButtonItem is not calling action

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I've problems with my NavAction where the item button is not calling defined action after touching. I've defined UIBarButtonItem outside of viewDidload function:

```
let uploadButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "UPLOAD", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(uploadHandler))
```

and then I'm adding it into NavBar (in viewDidLoad()):

```
self.navigationItem.setRightBarButton(uploadButton, animated: true)
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem!.setTitleTextAttributes([.font : UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 14, weight: .heavy), .foregroundColor : UIColor.label], for: .normal)
```

If I'm clicking on the button, nothing happening, action is not called, but if I will click on textView or textField and started typing, after that If I'll click on the button, action will be called. I've tried to resignFirstResponder in idea that is the problem but it doesn't help. Any ideas ? Thanx in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `uploadButton` is getting initialized too early, i.e. during the initialization of the view controller ifself. At that point, `self` is not yet ready for use.

There are a few ways to solve this.

1. Initialize the button in `viewDidLoad`:

```swift
class MyViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let uploadButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "UPLOAD", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(uploadHandler)) 
        self.navigationItem.setRightBarButton(uploadButton, animated: false)
    }
    ...
}
```

2. If some other methods in your class need access to it, slightly modify the code above by creating an implicitly unwrapped stored property and setting it in `viewDidLoad`:

```swift
class MyViewController: UIViewController {

    private var uploadButton: UIBarButtonItem!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        uploadButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "UPLOAD", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(uploadHandler)) 
        self.navigationItem.setRightBarButton(uploadButton, animated: false)
    }
    ...
}
```

3. Make the initialization of the button lazy, that way it will be initialized when it's first accessed, i.e. in viewDidLoad:

```swift
class MyViewController: UIViewController {

    private lazy var uploadButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "UPLOAD", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(uploadHandler)) 

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.navigationItem.setRightBarButton(uploadButton, animated: false)
    }
    ...
}
```

4. Initialize the button without an action and a selector, add them later in `viewDidLoad`:

```swift
class MyViewController: UIViewController {

    private let uploadButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "UPLOAD", style: .plain, target: nil, action: nil) 

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        uploadButton.target = self
        uploadButton.action = #selector(uploadHandler)
        self.navigationItem.setRightBarButton(uploadButton, animated: false)
    }
    ...
}
```

There's very little difference among all these options, so it should be fine whatever one you choose.

A couple of side notes:

- In my examples I declared `uploadButton` as private to indicate that it is not a part of your view controller's public API. If you need to access this button outside of your view controller, just remove the `private` modificator.
- Animation doesn't get performed in `viewDidLoad` because your view is not yet on screen, so calling `setRightBarButton(uploadButton, animated: true)` will not trigger the animation, therefore I replaced `true` with `false`. If you want the user to see the animation, call it in `viewDidAppear`.

Comment: Very appreciate your answer, especialy side notes. It worked !